# Raspberry Pi Wifi not scannning

Tags: wifi, gui, wpa

I am using the Official Raspberry Pi adapter for my Pi but I can not scan for networks in the wpa_gui window like I should be able to. Under the tab "Current Status" in the "Status" field, it states that it "could not get status from wpa_supplicant" 
Here are screenshots of my /etc/network/interfaces file and my /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf files.
[image: Network]
[image: wpa]

Answer (score 1):

On the command line as root,try iwlist wlanX scan where X is the index reference
obtained from the list under /sys/class/net. If it results in a list of all networks,then your wpa_supplicant.conf may have incorrect syntax.The image is too small to decipher

Comment: I have tried the command you suggested but it simply said there were no scan results. I have sorted out the size of my images so hopefully you will be able to see the properly now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are few additional things you could try

Examine the output from dmesg for any errors,drivers that are not loaded or those that do not exist.

If you have a tool called hwinfo, try hwinfo --netcard and look at its output

I have a similar situation like yours, an unbranded USB wireless card that displays similar noncan results. Mine is broken i guess,since it does not function under PC also.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have modified `/etc/network/interfaces` (for whatever reason). Put it back the way it was. The following shows the correct file contents (as well as how to setup).

[How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921)

If you are having problems with a WiFi interface there are a few steps to check.

Before going through these confirm your Power Supply. WiFi sticks can draw quite a lot of current.

A late model Pi (one with a 40 pin GPIO connector) should have an improved power circuit and should run most modules PROVIDED YOU HAVE AN ADEQUATE PS which can deliver at least 1A (more if you have other peripherals).

Earlier models quite often could not supply adequate current to USB devices, so you should try a powered hub. (This doesn't hurt even with later models if the PS is marginal).

1. Confirm whether the WiFi stick is being detected:-

Run a `lsusb` in a terminal and you should see your WiFi stick in the output of the command. e.g.

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

2. Check whether the driver module for the stick is loaded.

Run a `lsusb -t` in a terminal and you should see a Driver. e.g.

```
    |__ Port 4: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rt2800usb, 480M
```

`lsmod` will show all loaded modules, but it can be difficult to tell which is the driver

3. Check if the NIC is associated.

Run `ifconfig -a` and check the output. You should see a 'wlan0' in the output, e.g.

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c1:40:50:02:69
          inet addr:10.1.1.21  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::cab2:2c63:580d:aafa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2335 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:310332 (303.0 KiB)  TX bytes:258712 (252.6 KiB)
```

`dmesg -T | grep wlan` should show the bootlog messages.

If any of the above fail, there can be many causes. There is no blanket solution, but at least you can ask an intelligent question to get help.

Comment: I have fixed the file but it still says that it cannot get status from wpa_supplicant...